# how to iterate through html table using selenium javascript and node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium

I want to get values in html table using selenium javascript and node.js. I have a table in which `<td>` can hold links or `<input>` tags.

I have the `<tr>` XPATH as :

```
//*[@id="domainpricing"]/tbody/tr[0]
```

Here's the code:

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath('//*[@id="domainpricing"]/tbody/tr'))
.then(function(elems){
  console.log("len"+elems);            
});
```

'til now, I am able to select the `<tr>` tag, but how do I get all the elements in the `<td>` for all `<tr>`'s?

Answer (score 0):

I am only gessing, but is it simply adding `/td` to your path? Otherwise find again in elems using findElements for each in a loop?